# How to order data based on some coulmn in sequelize

Tags: sql, node.js, postgresql, typescript, sequelize.js

I have a table which has multiples entries, each with foreign key either 1,2 or 3.
The name of the column which is fk is "fkid".
I want to use a select query which gives me result in which **entries are grouped on the basis of foreign key.**

The result should have entries with *fkid=1 grouped together, fkid=2* together and so on.

Answer (score 0):

Try the below...

```
<model_name>.findAll({
   group: 'fkid'
});
```